# wavesurfer.js - getting it to work in browsers other than Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm looking for an html5 audio and video player that has a waveform.  I found wavesurfer.js, but that looks like just audio.  But hey, I thought I'd play around with it.  Here is some very simple code (this is just me with an html file on my desktop - and wav was converted to PCM.  Though, I've tried this with a wav and mp3):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/1.3.7/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>
<script>
var wavesurfer = Object.create(WaveSurfer);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    wavesurfer.init({
        container: '#waveform',
        waveColor: '#A8DBA8',
        progressColor: '#3B8686'
    });

   wavesurfer.load('session.wav');
});

wavesurfer.on('ready', function () {
    wavesurfer.play();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="waveform"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This couldn't get any simpler!  OK, let's open this in Firefox:

[image]

Great!  It starts playing.  I have a waveform.  Awesome!

Now Chrome (or Edge - both do the same):

[image]

Absolutely nothing (*scratches head*).  No sound.  Nothing.

OK, I found this link here: https://wavesurfer-js.org/example/audio-element/

It says: wavesurfer.js will automatically fallback to HTML5 Media if Web Audio is not supported. However, you can choose to use audio element manually. Simply set the backend option to "MediaElement"

Without googling (listen I'm jumping in the pool feet first here!), I guess I don't know the exact difference between HTML 5 Media and Web Audio.  Or my assumption off my head is Web Audio means the HTML 5 Audio tag, which is different from HTML 5 Media How?  Not sure yet.  I know nothing.

Regardless, I'll change that code I posted above and add one line of code to the init function:

```
wavesurfer.init({
    container: '#waveform',
    waveColor: '#A8DBA8',
    progressColor: '#3B8686',
    backend: 'MediaElement'
});
```

Running in Chrome now, I get:

[image]

It plays.  But no waveform.

I mean, I go to the wavesurfer.js website with Chrome and all the demos work.  I don't get it.  On top of that, I'm concerned about forcing things with the 'MediaElement' backend property.

What am I missing?

**EDIT: Oh for goodness sake.  I took the same html5.html file (without the back end 'MediaElement' property) and session.wav file and placed them on a web server (IIS).  Now, I'm fetching the page through a web server instead of working local to my desktop.  Works in Edge and Chrome (and Opera - tried that too!) - No problem.  Must be something about working locally that Chrome and Edge don't like.  I'll leave this question open - green check marks await for that person that adds valuable info!**

Comment: I might be wrong as I haven't tested this in Firefox in a while, but I know that Chrome in particular only allows the Web Audio API in `https:` protocol for security reasons. Can you open the developer console (like you should always do as due diligence before posting a question on Stack Overflow) and see if there is a security exception thrown in Chrome when testing on `file:`?

Comment: Also, just noticed one of your implicit questions. The Web Audio API is what allows access to and manipulation of binary data for sound files, either streaming or statically. The HTML5  Media API just allows you to use an `<audio>` tag to embed sound files in the HTML document.

Comment: As I was typing this question, and uploading images to tinypic, a light went on in my head: I wonder if it has something to do with working locallly (file:).  And yup, my hunches were correct.  So it's file: that's the issue.  Not https:.  And as someone who has done more Visual Studio development ... I do need to get used to using the developer tools in the browser!  Good point.  Here was the Chrome error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/me/Desktop/session.wav. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: As for the implicit question: Your words sound like they should make sense to me, but not completely there yet.  You mention HTML5 Media just allows you to embed sound files.  OK.  And that's not the same as accessing and manipulating binary data for sound files?  Which is what you said the Web Audio API is?  Forgive me, not clicking yet.  I need to visualize this in some way!

Comment: What I mean is that the Web Audio API gives you _programmatic access to binary data through JavaScript_. If you're familiar with the Canvas API, it's like this: [HTML5 Media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement) is to [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) as [`<img>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) is to [`ctx.getImageData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData)

Comment: Patrick, thanks so much.  I tried upvoting every one of your comments, so hopefully that gets you some reputation points.  You're awesome.

Comment: It doesn't, but I appreciate the sentiment. Since I didn't actually answer your question, I don't expect reputation, I'm just glad to help clarify some concepts for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome (in an effort to maintain better security involving file system access) prevents the dynamic loading of anything from the file protocol.  This (as well as a deep discussion about why this is both a good idea and a bad idea) is referenced here:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47416

My personal favorite quote is this one (I have so been this guy in the past):

> Your local file policy is 'over the top' as regards security and I urge you to reconsider, please don't fall into the trap of making your browser so secure that it ceases to be useful or usable. Allow the user to decide as Microsoft do with a simple option choice or, God help me, another yellow bar.

You can disable this by launching Chrome with the command line argument `--allow-file-access-from-files` or by (as you found out) just spinning up a web server, if you want an even easier server I would recommend Python's [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) which you can start from any directory (in Windows, Mac OSX and Linux) by typing `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` (it comes standard with any version of Python)

Comment: Hah! Awesome quote. IIRC, don't they have a command-line flag or something, `--disable-web-security`? Or did they remove that too?

Comment: Dude, awesome.  I kind of stumbled upon this (figuring it had something to do with working locally).  But your awesome explanation explains why that is.  And I like that you added the SimpleHTTPServer tidbit.  Nice!